# How does compiler generate template class definitions?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following header files.

In my `Object.h`

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H_
#define OBJECT_H_

#include <iostream>

template <class Policy>
class Object
{
  friend Policy;
 private:
  Policy* p;
  int hash;

 public:
 Object():p(new Policy(this)),hash(0){}
  ~Object(){delete p;}

  void set(){p->setHash();}

  void show() const{std::cout<<"hash = "<<hash<<std::endl;}
};

#endif // OBJECT_H_
```

Then I created two Policies, P1 and P2, with different hash values.

In `p1.h`

```
#ifndef P1_H_
#define P1_H_

template <class Policy> class Object;

class P1
{
  enum {p1 = 1}; 
  Object<P1>* t;

 public:
  P1(Object<P1>* at):t(at){}
  void setHash(){t->hash = p1;}
};

#endif // P1_H_
```

In `p2.h`

```
#ifndef P2_H_
#define P2_H_

template <class Policy> class Object;
class P2
{
 enum {p2 = 2};

 Object<P2>* t;

 public:
 P2(Object<P2>* at):t(at){}
 //void setHash(){t->hash = p2;} // ** Notice here **
};
#endif // P2_H_
```

In my `main.cpp` I have

```
#include "Object.h"
#include "p1.h"
#include "p2.h"

int main()
{
  Object<P1> t1;
  t1.set();
  t1.show();

  Object<P2> t2;
  //t2.set();
  t2.show();
}
```

**Result** on OS X:

hash = 1

hash = 0

**Observations**:

1. It will compile and run properly. Notice the definition of `Object<P2>` is even not complete. Since P2 have not defined setHash().
2. If I get rid of the comment in my main, then it will report an error.

   ./Object.h:20:8: error: no member named 'setHash' in 'P2'

   main.cpp:12:6: note: in instantiation of member function          'Object::set' requested here t2.set();

**Questions**

1. Consider the Object member inside P1 or P2 class would compiler generate class definition for each of them even if I do not create an instance of `Object<P1>` or `Object<P2` in main?
2. Why `Object<P2>` is OK? Since the definition is incomplete.

Comment: "then it will report an error" Which is?

Comment: @user657267 added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Consider the Object member inside P1 or P2 class would compiler generate class definition for each of them even if I do not create an instance of `Object<P1>` or `Object<P2>` in main?

No.  The members are `Object<P1>* t;` and `Object<P1>* t;` - they're not `static` so are only created when `P1` and `P2` object instances are created, and they're pointers so even then no `Object<P1>*` is created: the pointer passed to the constructor - which may be `nullptr` / `0` - is simply stored.

> Why Object is OK? Since the definition is incomplete.

With templates, functions are only instantiated when called.  As long as they can be parsed properly, it is not an error.

Comment: Thanks. I see now.

Answer (score 1):

There are no `Object<P1>` or `Object<P2>` members inside `P1` and `P2`. There are `Object<P1>*`  and `Object<P2>*` members. A pointer to an incomplete type is perfectly OK. The type itself will not be instantiated unless the pointer is dereferenced.

In your `main` function, `Object<P2>` is a complete type, but its non-virtual member functions are still not instantiated unless called (or rather, technically, ODR-used). This is why it is OK to have `Object<P2> t2;` but calling `t2.set()` is an error.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Tony D.